# Trying to convert Unreal shader graph to Unity, what nodes are a close equivalent in the Unity shader graph?

Tags: unity, shaders

I am trying to convert an Unreal shader graph to a Unity Shader Graph.

https://api.unrealengine.com/udk/Three/VolumetricLightbeamTutorial.html

I am struggling with understanding which nodes to use in the Unity Shader Graph while trying to replicate it.

I managed to get something looking Ok using the fresnel node, but if you enter inside the geometry, you lose the effect.  I found the above article which is perfect for what I need to do.

Here is the first node setup:

[image: first]

I tried to follow along but a lot of the nodes I don't understand what the equivalent would be in the Unity shader graph.

Combine looks to be the equivalent of the Append node I think.
Mask node I am not sure about as there are 3 mask nodes in Unity shader graph.

Edit:

Spent most of the weekend trying to learn which nodes to use.  Still not sure on what the "Reflection Vector" should be.  I think it's something to do with the camera.

Here is the graph currently.

[image]